# How can i handle push notification in IMF8?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an application using cordova and ibm mobile first 8 and wanted to integrate a push notification system.
I registre the device in the server and i can send the notification from the server to client app then the client app handle a received push notification by operating on its response object in the registered callback function :

```
var notificationReceived = function(message) {
alert(JSON.stringify(message));
};
```

Here is my issues :
[alert issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfRSX.png)

I don't want the alert to be displayed. 
And I want that when I click on the notification A function is called.

how can i do this ? Please i need your help thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet you have in your question there is an `alert`. Remove the `alert` snippet and no alert dialog will be displayed...

You can then put there instead anything else you'd like, like logging the notification contents, or performing any other action, like calling a function.

```
var notificationReceived = function(message) {
myFunction();
};

function myFunction() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: idanAdar  the notification only work when i'am in background ? do you have an idea how to handle it in foreground ?

Comment: When it was an alert, did it work also in the foreground? The answer should be "yes". If yes, then you're doing something wrong in your code and I can't help you. You need to share your project.

Comment: the answer is yes : i'm doing the same things in the doc https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/cordova/#notifications-api    just i removed the alert from notificationReceived

Comment: can you please help me in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227847/cant-receive-push-notification-in-ios   thank you