# Can't receive push notification in iOS?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

Im trying to send notification with IBM mobile first 8 but i can't receive notification in IOS .

The deviceId is well registered to IMF server But when i try to test and send notification from server to my app .the notification is not received .

I used this doc : https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PushNotificationsCordova/blob/release80/www/js/index.js

I can receive notification in Android .

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

You only point to the javascript file, not to the instructions that you followed. You should edit your question with detailed step-by-step review of what you've done.

Additionally, for iOS you should also make sure that Keychain sharing is enabled in your Xcode settings.